# PHP and GD library add 1px solid border to a text? I'm getting a border like dots

Tags: php, border, gd

Heres how I'm getting the text:

[image: test]

I wanted to add a solid border to the text, even if the border were pure black...

here is my code:

```
<?php
    $text = ($_GET['txt'] ? $_GET['txt'] : '?');
    $text = strtoupper($text[0]).substr($text,1,strlen($text));
    $size = ($_GET['size'] ? $_GET['size'] : 15);
    $sizex = 120;
    $sizey = 28;
    $x = 4;
    $y = 20;
    $color = ($_GET['color'] ? $_GET['color'] : 'efcfa4');
        $red = (int)hexdec(substr($color,0,2));
        $green = (int)hexdec(substr($color,2,2));
        $blue = (int)hexdec(substr($color,4,2));
    $img = imagecreatetruecolor($sizex,$sizey);
    ImageColorTransparent($img, ImageColorAllocate($img,0,0,0));

    imagettftext($img, $size, 0, $x, $y, ImageColorAllocate($img,$red,$green,$blue), 'martel.ttf', $text);

    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($img);
    imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

the picture generated with the text data is taken from this line in another page:

```
<img src="pages/scripts/font1.php?txt=test&color=cccccc&size=15">
```

Comment: I don't get it, why this question is being negativated? What did I do wrong? I just need to know where I'm supposed to edit to place a border because in the php manual I couldn't find anything related to the border in `imagefttext` or `imagecreatetruecolor`

Comment: Not sure if it has anything to do with your problem, but I think that since you are using a .ttf font file you should use the `imagettftext` instead of `imagefttext`

Comment: and a small side note.. about your second line.. there's a function for that: ucfirst

Comment: @mishu thanks I actually know that function, but I didn't know what that second line functions were supposed to do so I wouldn't mess with that...

Comment: switched the `imagefttext` with `imagettftext` and seemed pretty much same thing, but I'll keep your suggestion, thanks! I've tried editing the `ImageColorAllocate` many ways but all it changes is the font color, not the border size or color tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
<?php

function imagettfstroketext(&$image, $size, $angle, $x, $y, &$textcolor, &$strokecolor, $fontfile, $text, $px) {
    for($c1 = ($x-abs($px)); $c1 <= ($x+abs($px)); $c1++)
        for($c2 = ($y-abs($px)); $c2 <= ($y+abs($px)); $c2++)
            $bg = imagettftext($image, $size, $angle, $c1, $c2, $strokecolor, $fontfile, $text);
   return imagettftext($image, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $textcolor, $fontfile, $text);
}

// Create new canvas
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(170,  60);

// Set background to white
$gray = imagecolorallocate($im, 100, 100, 100);
imagefill($im, 0, 0, $gray);

// Set fron color and border color
$font_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$stroke_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

//image, fontsize, angle, x, y, textcolor, bordercolor, font file, text, borderwidth
imagettfstroketext($im, 60, 0, 10, 50, $font_color, $stroke_color, "martel.ttf", "test", 2);

// Output
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, how would I link those options inside the function? in the html line I would have to add the value of each option there? where is that ( $image ) coming from?

Comment: UPDATE: thanks I figured it out... The transparent background is what makes the border get messed up... when I set a color to the background the border stays just fine